# How to use Function key and Standard key in extended apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, fn-key, macos-sonoma

I'm using an extended Apple keyboard which is quite old and does not have globe / fn key which handle function key and standard key behaviour in main keyboad.

How can I use fn and standard key by which keyboard shortcut?

There is no modifier key available for fn key also.

Can someone help me here? macOS Sonoma